# Delegate on few web views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swift2

I run into a situation where i want to register delegate on TWO separate web views on same viewController.  I have two web views and I want to register webViewDidFinishLoad for "webView_one" and webViewDidFinishLoad for "webView_two".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have set the delegate for your webViews:

```
optional func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if webView == webView_one {
        //do something 
    } else { 
       // webView is webView_two 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this if you have 2 webview in the same viewcontroller:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    if webView == webView_one {
        // Do something with webview one
    } else {
        // Do something with other webview
    }
}
```